# Globus Personal Connect: Tcllib installed, but keeps showing "tcllib not found" error

Tags: software-installation, tcl

Trying to use Globus Personal Connect on my Ubuntu 16.04, and it requires Tcllib. I have tcllib installed (the newest version), but it still says "Tcllib not found" when I try to access the Globus Connect via "./globusconnect" command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tcllib
[sudo] password for usdandres: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tcllib is already the newest version (1.17-dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.

$ ./globusconnect
Tcllib not found.
The Globus Connect Personal GUI requires Tcllib.
Please install Tcllib using your distributions package management system.
On Debian based systems (e.g. Ubunutu):
  apt-get install tcllib
On Redhat based systems (e.g. CentOS, Fedora):
  yum install tcllib

 Note: if you encounter an error about tcllib not being
 available, it can be found here and installed manually:
 http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/

You may also run Globus Connect Personal in CLI mode.

Please use the -help option or visit http://globus.org/globus-connect-personal/
for more information.
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I encountered this problem trying to compile linuxcnc, my solution was `sudo apt-get install tcl8.6-dev tcl-dev `

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM I have successfully launched it with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://downloads.globus.org/globus-connect-personal/linux/stable/globusconnectpersonal-latest.tgz
tar -xf globusconnectpersonal-latest.tgz
cd globusconnectpersonal-2.3.6/
sudo apt-get install tcllib tcl tk
```

and got its window after execution of `./globusconnect`.

If you suspect that Anaconda is a problem and fear to break it, then you can manually change the PATH variable with

`export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

and then try to launch it from the same terminal with

```
./globusconnect
```

Or in one-line version:

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" ./globusconnect`

Comment: This resulted in the same error for me.

Comment: Are you running 64-bit OS or 32-bit? What is the output of `arch` command?

Comment: 64 bit, `x86_64`. I know that Anaconda is installed on my computer so I'm concerned I have the same issue as @climatestudent. I'm such a Ubuntu noob that internet searches aren't getting me anywhere and I'm worried about messing up my .profile files.

Comment: Then try to manually specify PATH variable by `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`  and try to launch `./globusconnect` then from the same terminal.

Comment: I can see that I have a number of files... `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, .`bashrc-anaconda3.bak`, and `.profile`

Comment: !!!!!! amazing!!! This solved my problem. I wish I could buy you a beer!

Comment: The one-liner worked on 18.04 `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" ./globusconnect &`

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Globus Connect Personal 2.3.6. In my case the problem appears to have been caused by my Anaconda installation obscuring the Tcllib installed by the package manager. Creating and activating a new conda environment did not resolve the problem, nor did trying to install tcl from conda. My workaround was to temporarily remove the path to Anaconda from my PATH environment variable for the bash session in which I run `./globusconnect`.

Comment: I'm just getting started with ubuntu and I think I might have the same problem. Can you describe the code you used to temporarily remove the path to Anaconda and then put it back?

Comment: @Nova, there are probably better ways, but I did `echo $PATH`, copied the output without the path involving `anaconda3/bin` and then set the `PATH=` the rest of the sequence output.

Comment: If you start a new terminal session, anaconda will automatically be included in your `$PATH` again. Otherwise you can reset the `PATH=` back to the original path including anaconda once you are done with globusconnect.